# PyGame change preset soundfont

Tags: python, pygame, midi, fluidsynth

How do I change the preset soundfonts for pygame or fluidsynth?

Im using Python 3.7.3, pygame 2.0.1, fluidsynth 1.1.11 to play Midi files. When I call pygame.mixer.music.load(<midi_filepath>), I receive a few fluidsynth errors:

`fluidsynth: error: Unable to open file "/usr/share/sounds/sf3/FluidR3Mono_GM.sf3" fluidsynth: error: Couldn't load soundfont file fluidsynth: error: Failed to load SoundFont "/usr/share/sounds/sf3/FluidR3Mono_GM.sf3" fluidsynth: error: Unable to open file "/usr/share/sounds/sf2/TimGM6mb.sf2" fluidsynth: error: Couldn't load soundfont file fluidsynth: error: Failed to load SoundFont "/usr/share/sounds/sf2/TimGM6mb.sf2"`

These soundfont files are not on my device. So I'd like to point fluidsynth to another soundfont. How do I change the preset soundfonts for fluidsynth inside PyGame?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to change the preset soundsfonts, but I was able to install the missing soundfonts.

`apt-get install fluidr3mono-gm-soundfont` for `FluidR3Mono_GM.sf3`

`apt-get install timgm6mb-soundfont` for `TimGM6mb.sf2`

Answer (score 0):

I found your question here because I have it too. But somehow questions about Pygame do not seem to get answered (fast) here.

But there is a very active mail list on topics regarding Pygame.

http://pygame-users.25799.x6.nabble.com/

You have to register first. But it did not take me long and I got a pretty good answer for another question ridiculously fast!

If you get a good answer through the mail list maybe you could post it here, too. Just in case other people are searching for the same thing.